# Columns with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called Employee that contains the following information like

```
ID      Name       Skills   

1       xyz        java,php,dotnet

2       abc        ruby,java,python
```

Skills column saves comma seprated values. it could be one or more.

I want to design a query based on `OR` operate.When user search java, Database displays two employees likes xyz, abc.

I have tried this query but no result comes out:

```
SELECT m 
FROM Employee m 
Where m.Skills LIKE '%JAVA% MS PAINT%'
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Please do not store data as a comma separated list.  You need to have a separate table to associate the user to a skill.

Comment: Show your code please. FYI, this is a very poor format of the database. You should never store comma-separated values there.

Comment: What would be the structure of that table? and what sort of query i i'll write?

Comment: 1 - xyz - java/ 1 - xyz - php/ 1 - xyz - dotnet and so on. Or two separate tables, one storing names, another matching ID and Skills.

Comment: Then you can do SELECT Name FROM Employee WHERE Skills = "java" or SELECT Name FROM Employee JOIN Skillstable s ON s.id = id WHERE s.skillname = "java"

Comment: you would have an additional table that has a row for each item in the skills list that ties to the ID

Comment: ok great. How could i write query if i want to search employee with Java or Ruby skills?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should not store the data in a comma-separated list. You should create a join table between the employees and the skills:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (`e_id` int, `e_name` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO employees (`e_id`, `e_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'xyz'),
    (2, 'abc');

CREATE TABLE skills (`s_id` int, `s_name` varchar(6));

INSERT INTO skills (`s_id`, `s_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'java'),
    (2, 'php'),
    (3, 'dotnet'),
    (4, 'ruby'),
    (5, 'python');

CREATE TABLE employees_skills (`e_d` int, `s_id` int);

INSERT INTO employees_skills
    (`e_d`, `s_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 5);
```

Then when you want to select from the tables you will use:

```
select *
from employees e
inner join employees_skills es
  on e.e_id = es.e_id
inner join skills s
  on es.s_is = s.s_id
where s.s_name in ('java', 'ruby')
```

Or you can use the `OR` clause:

```
select *
from employees e
inner join employees_skills es
  on e.e_id = es.e_id
inner join skills s
  on es.s_is = s.s_id
where s.s_name = 'java'
   or s.s_name = 'ruby'
```

Comment: thanks. what sort of query i'll write to fetch data based on "OR" condition?. like Java or Ruby??

Comment: @user1030128 that is the `WHERE` clause -- `where s.s_name in ('java', 'ruby')`. The `IN` will return rows with either the java or ruby skills.

Answer (score 1):

use like not good solution. Full scan and slow query.
Create new table with catalog of skills.
Create table user_skills

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your tables like this:

```
Employee:
ID | Name
---+------
1  | xyz
2  | abc

Skill:
ID | Name
---+------
1  | java
2  | php
3  | dotnet
4  | ruby
5  | python

EmployeeSkills:
ID | EmployeeID | SkillID
---+------------+----------
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 2
3  | 1          | 3
4  | 2          | 4
5  | 2          | 1
6  | 2          | 5
```

the query to find employees with skills in java would look like this

```
SELECT
    E.Name
FROM
    Employee AS E
INNER JOIN
    EmployeeSkill AS ES
ON
    ES.EmployeeID = E.ID
INNER JOIN
    Skill AS S
ON
    ES.SkillID = S.ID
WHERE
    S.Name = 'java'
```

Comment: Tnanks Macro..Much appreciated for your effort. It works but how can i find data if i supply Java or Ruby? Both employee should come based on OR Operator...

Comment: you can change the constraint either to `S.Name = 'java' OR S.Name = 'ruby'` or to `S.Name IN ('java','ruby')` - not sure which will be executed faster atm

Comment: using in operator or like?

Comment: edited previous comment - hope its better to read now. no like operator!

Answer (score -1):

`select name from table where skill like '%java%'` should do

Comment: SELECT m FROM Employee m Where m.Skills LIKE '%JAVA% MS PAINT%'.. NO RESULT WHY? –

Comment: you should write SELECT * FROM Employee m Where m.Skills LIKE '%JAVA% ' OR m.Skills LIKE '%MS PAINT%'.